# How to dynamically pass params into a click event method in angular 2

Tags: javascript, parameters, angular, parameter-passing

My service returns some data and i use it into my View.
I'm trying to pass a specific ID into my onDivClick method on a click event.

I want to do something like that but it's not working :

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data" class="widget-body no-padding">
  <a class="list-group-item" href="#" (click)="onDivClick({{d.data_id}})">
       ...
  </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: and what does the onDivClick method look like?

Answer (score 4):

Just remove `{{}}`

```
 <a class="list-group-item" href="#" (click)="onDivClick(d.data_id)">
```

If you have `()` or `[]` you must not use `{{}}` as well